# How to create a FreeRTOS task in another task?

Tags: c, task, freertos

I am currently working on the i.MX8M Mini processor and especially on the i.MX 8M Mini Evaluation Kit.
I'm trying to get this piece of code to work, which is supposed to launch a FreeRTOS task that itself performs instructions and creates two other tasks.
From what I understand, the tasks are only really launched when the `vTaskStartScheduler()` function is executed.
However, in my code, the `vTaskStartScheduler()` function starts the `rpmsg_task` task but not the tasks normally started by this same task.

So my question is: how can I create (and run) a task from another task (after the execution of `vTaskStartScheduler()`)?

Here is my code :

```
int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize standard SDK demo application pins */
    /* Board specific RDC settings */
    BOARD_RdcInit();

    BOARD_InitBootPins();
    BOARD_BootClockRUN();
    BOARD_InitDebugConsole();
    BOARD_InitMemory();

    copyResourceTable();

#ifdef MCMGR_USED
    /* Initialize MCMGR before calling its API */
    (void)MCMGR_Init();
#endif /* MCMGR_USED */

    if (xTaskCreate(rpmsg_task, "rpmsg_task", RPMSG_TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1, &rpmsg_task_handle) != pdPASS)
    {
        PRINTF("\r\nFailed to create rpmsg_rx_task\r\n");
        for (;;)
            ;
    }

    vTaskStartScheduler();

    PRINTF("Failed to start FreeRTOS on core0.\n");
    for (;;)
        ;
}
```

Comment: You can create new tasks after starting the scheduler using `xTaskCreate()`, in the same way as before starting the scheduler.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was already doing. But how to properly run this new task from the initial task.

Comment: It's already running after creation.